# How to split machine learning data based on class?

Tags: python, dataset

I am trying to split (X_train, Y_train) based on the different classes of Y_train. X_train consists of 50,000 25 X 25 images, and Y_train consists of 50,000 binary classifications (0 or 1). I tried to put the data with the code below

```
def split(X_train, Y_train):
    if Y_train == 0:
       0_only = []
       0_only.append(X_train)
```

Comment: `train_test_split` from `sklearn` might be helpful: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may do what you want:

```
# Find the indices of the samples in Y_train that are zero
idx_zero = np.where(Y_train == 0)[0]

# Get subset of X_train and Y_train where Y_train is zero
X_train_zero = X_train[idx_zero]
Y_train_zero = Y_train[idx_zero]
```

Then you could do the same thing with `np.where(Y_train == 1)[0]`.

Comment: Is there a way to make the idx_zero iterable without having "ones?" For example, if I do idx_zero[1], it returns an error because the label is a one. Is it possible so when I do id_zero[1], it selects the next zero in the list?

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean. `idx_zero` is an array containing the indices corresponding to elements in `Y_train` that are equal to zero. Could you clarify what you are trying to do?